# Windows 10 + Ubuntu VMWare + Iptables

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vmware-player

I've been trying to set up a firewall on linux with iptables in a virtual machine (Laptop).

The goal is to manage all traffic inside my home network.

The configurations i'm using are the following:

Vmware configurations - Ubuntu System:

- 2 NICs, one doing bridge with the physical wireless card and another one Host-only
- Home router: 192.168.1.*

**Bridged Connection:**

```
IP: 192.168.1.102

 MASK: 255.255.255.0

 GATEWAY: 192.168.1.1
```

**Host only**

```
 IP: 192.168.17.129

 MASK: 255.255.255.0

 GATEWAY: 192.168.17.255
```

**Windows 10 - Host machine
Wireless static ip**

```
 IP: 192.168.17.130

 MASK: 255.255.255.0

 GATEWAY: 192.168.17.129

 DNS: 192.168.17.129
```

However with this configurtions from the host i can't access internet...

Can someone help me out with this?

Thanks

Comment: When you say that you "can't access Internet", what **exactly** do you mean by that? How did you determine that you are unable to access the Internet? You can [edit] your question to add further details.